# flexmojo java heap space error

Tags: java, maven, heap-memory, flexmojos

When I lunch maven flexMojo compile plugin  from eclipse in windows OS I get java heap space error .
any idea on increasing memory for maven ? 
I tired this in windows envirement variables :

```
MVN_OPTS = -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

and it didn't help .

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be *MAVEN_OPTS* instead of *MVN_OPTS*?

Answer (score 0):

Some one [post](http://www.flexonjava.net/2011/06/sts-with-maven-javalangoutofmemoryerror.html) the answer in the web . a copy paste from the original post :

The solution obviously is to increase the maximum heap size which is represented by the JVM -Xmx argument. Now there are a number of places you can find this argument (STS.ini is one of them) , but here's the one place I found that really makes the difference.

Goto the 'Run Configurations' popup of the current maven run you are trying to use (can be accesed by right clicking your project and selecting 'Run As')
Select your current run under 'Maven Build' in the tree
Select the the JVM tab and add your requested -Xmx settings (I chose -Xmx512m)
Press 'Apply' and 'Run'

Comment: No link-only-answes please! Add the relevant content to your answer.